# jQuery Dropdown Menu with Android

Tags: android, jquery

I wrote this script for a navigation menu on the phone. If an item has drop downs, it prevents the link, then displays the drpdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
    if(bodyWidth <= 600) {
      $('ul.dropdowns li > a').click(function(event) {
        var parent = $(this).closest('li');
        var nester = $(this).closest('li').closest('ul').closest('li');
        var type = parent.attr("class");
        if(parent.hasClass('dropdown') || parent.hasClass('flyout')) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(parent).siblings().attr("id", "");
          var isActive = (parent.attr("id") == "active" ? true : false);
          (isActive ? $(parent).attr("id", "") : $(parent).attr("id", "active"));
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

This works fine with the iPhone, but on Android it gets screwed. I'm at a total loss, any ideas?

By, "gets screwed" I mean nothing happens on Android when you try to click a link.

Comment: we will have to see your code working to be able to give some advice. Try posting a working fiddle and explain what happens in android devices

Comment: http://plovetttesting.tk/build/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using a CSS transition that for some reason Android wasn't keeping up with.